# How do I let an employer know to hurry up with their decision since I have already been offered another position?

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I have recently interviewed at two companies, and one of the companies has given me and offer which expires in 2 weeks. The other company (I want to work for this one), has still to make a decision.

I don't want to let go of the other offer in the case that if I don't get to work with the company that I want, I still have the other one to secure.

I want to let this company (the one I **want** to work with), know that they only have 2 weeks to offer me a position, or I will have to accept the other role.

What can I send the HR?

I want to say something like this to the company HR:

**I have recently been offered a position at company B, which I must choose to accept or decline within a 2 week period. Please let me know if you have considered me for a candidate or not**

Comment: Instead of "must choose to accept or decline within a 2 week period", I'd say "company B wants me to accept or decline their offer within a 2 week period". I wouldn't say "please let me know if you have considered me for a candidate or not", that should be common sense for them.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I send the HR?

Just explain that you have an offer at another company, and you have to make a decision soon. They will understand what it means in relationship to their company.

If they have gone far enough in their interview process, have pretty much reached a decision, and want you badly enough, they will try to speed up their offer. Otherwise, they will wish you good luck with your job.

> I want to say something like this to the company HR:
>
> I have recently been offered a position at company B, which I must
>   choose to accept or decline within a 2 week period. Please let me know
>   if you have considered me for a candidate or not.

This is okay, but you have to be ready to make your decision if they say something like "We are considering you as a candidate, but we cannot make our final decision in the next 2 weeks."

I've been the hiring manager in situations like this. Sometimes the timing just isn't right and you have to decide between a real offer and one that may or may not actually happen.